# Create all strings given character set k and lemgth n

Tags: python, math, permutation

So I couldn't find the exact answer for the following problem online.
If I have a set of characters `k` and I want to make all possible combinations within a string of length `n`, each character should appear at least once in the string and i say that `'abc' == 'cba'`.
I need some code that would get me these strings.(so without duplicates like `'abc' == 'cba'`) I tried several nested loops and recursive code blocks but neither got it working for me, hope you guys can help! (Python is my main language do if the answer could be in this language that would be great)

Example:

```
In:
chars = ['a', 'b', 'c']
length = 5
Out:
'abccc', 'abbcc', 'abbbc', 'aabcc', 'aabbc', 'aaabc'
```

Comment: Please post your attempt here. Stack Overflow is not a place where people write code for you.

Comment: Well writing the could is only an extra, if I understand the way of solving my problem I could write the code myself. Nonetheless thanks for your reply, I will add code the next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itertools` can get you most of the way there:

```
>>> def gen(s, count):
...     for comb in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(s, count):
...         if len(set(comb)) == len(s):
...             yield ''.join(comb)
...             
>>> [s for s in gen('abc', 5)]
['aaabc', 'aabbc', 'aabcc', 'abbbc', 'abbcc', 'abccc']
```

There is inefficiency in generating combinations that you're filtering out, but if it's not performance-critical code then don't worry about that prematurely.

Comment: Thank you! I should have know there is builtin function for this, will do a bit more research on the docs next time.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `itertools` for that:

```
import itertools

def generate_strings(chars,n):
    return [''.join(x) for x in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(chars,n) if all(c in x for c in chars)]
```

This is because `combinations_with_replacement(..)` generates, as the name says, tuples of the given elements, but where each element can occur many times. So:

```
>>> list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(['a','b'],3))
[('a', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'b'), ('b', 'b', 'b')]
```

Now we perform an additional filtering:

```
... if all(c in x for c in chars)
```

So we check if all characters are present in the string that we will generate.

Now we call `''.join(..)` on these to join the characters in the tuples together into a string. So for our sample above, we will generate `["aab","abb"]`.

For your given query it generates:

```
>>> generate_strings(['a','b','c'],5)
['aaabc', 'aabbc', 'aabcc', 'abbbc', 'abbcc', 'abccc']
```

Comment: "each character should appear at least once in the string"

Comment: @wim: fixed, better?

Answer (score 0):

Take unchanged part - here 'abc'

Generate all strings with length (n-k) using recursive way or another approach, here 'aa','ab','ac','bb','bc','cc'

Merge unchanged part with every generated string